# Firebase does not return error even though it should

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I am doing an experiment and found this weird issue where firebase returned with no error even though the data was not saved. Here is the code. ( I use angular 2 and AngularFire2 with typescript

Inside my forms.service.ts

```
test() {
    let myDate = new Date();
    const firRef = this.af.database.list('/test');
    return firRef.push({ date: myDate });
}
```

Inside my app.component.ts

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.formsService.test()
      .then((key) => {
        console.log('Success')
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log('Error', error)
      })
  }
```

And I received an output of "Success" from the console even though there was no entry going in the database. Shouldn't there be an error thrown in this case?

Comment: That seems weird. Can you set up a jsbin that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Hi Frank, I am not sure how to set this up on jsbin as I will also need to set up firebase with gmail etc. If you really require, I can set up a new gmail account with a brand new project in github? On a side note, I can see that firebase does not like date: myDate because when I do date: myDate.toLocaleDateString() the data gets updated to firebase. Could it be that firebase does not like to take Date() format? Though I saw somewhere that it does